# Eclipse e4 Extending a Perspective

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, e4

I am starting a new eclipse plug-in project and trying to evaluate what is the best approach.

What is the goal: I want to create a plug-in that adds a View/Editor stacked on the Editor of the C/C++ perspective from the CDT plug-in. Similar to XML editors that have highlighted text editor view and a view that contains a form to be filled and automatically creates xml code.

The best way would probably be to extend the existing C/C++ perspective from the CDT plug-in. How this is done wtih the 3.X API is explained here [[1](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_perspectiveExtension.htm),[2]](http://udig.refractions.net/files/docs/latest/1.3.2-SNAPSHOT/developer/extending_an_existing_perspective_example.html). Basically you use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point to add views realtive to the views in the perspective.

But how can this be done with the e4 API and the model fragment? Is this possible with compatibility layer?

I think another possibility would be to add views contained in the C/C++ perspective through the combability layer to my own perspective like the package explorer. This has the adavantage that already existing 3.X views (like the package explorer) can be used but also have the advantages of the e4 API.

Or would it even be the best to create a pure 3.X plug-in because my plug-in is mainly based on another perspective/plug-in?

Hope somebody can help me here :)

Comment: you should overthink your concept

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to extend a 3.x perspective using e4 model fragments. It is certainly easier to stick to the 3.x style.

You can use e4 style views by using the `e4view` style view on the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point.